# Flutter stopwatch background running

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a simple stopwatch application and I have so far implemented a stopwatch that is working while the app is running, but I want the stopwatch to continue to work while the application is closed and then resume while I open the app again. A similar app that I can compare to is RunKeeper which tracks the time of your running activities.

Is there any simple plugins that I can use to resolve my issue or is it more complicated than that?

So far I have tried using workmanager(flutter plugin) but with workmanager I could only track background activities at a given time, not the entire time the stopwatch is active, which I want in my case.

Comment: I had the same issue did you find any solution grading this problem if you find any solution let me know Simon

Answer (score 0):

I created a stopwatch by using a **Stream** that returns the time with the help of **Timer.periodic()**. If you quit to home screen of the phone the Stream keeps running in the background.

```
Stream<int> stopWatchStream() {
  StreamController<int> streamController;
  Timer timer;
  int counter = 0;

  void stopTimer() {
    if (timer != null) {
      timer.cancel();
      timer = null;
      counter = 0;
      streamController.close();
    }
  }

  void tick(_) {
    counter++;
    streamController.add(counter);
  }

  void startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 10), tick);
  }

  streamController = StreamController<int>(
    onListen: startTimer,
    onCancel: stopTimer,
    onResume: startTimer,
    onPause: stopTimer,
  );

  return streamController.stream;
}
```

Comment: I've tested your code, and it does work when the app is minimized, but do you know how to keep the timer running if you switch to a new page?